# Disable file search in Gnome Shell 40.5

Tags: command-line, gnome, search

is possible to disable file search in Gnome Shell search as you can see on screenshot?

I want only search for applications.

[image: Gnome Shell Search]

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 21, why do you ask?

Comment: I assume you mean 21.10 and not 21.04. I was not sure which one has gnome 40.5.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is something that can be controlled in the Settings:

[image: Settings - Search]

Toggle the items you do not want to be part of the search. The changes take effect immediately, so there is no need to sign out or restart.